# transitively join on output from join

Tags: shell, unix, join

Suppose I have data in the form (Sample.txt) :

`2 5
5 7
7 8
7 9
9 0`

I have used `join -o 1.2 <(sort Sample.txt) <(sort first.txt) > second.txt` The first.txt contains only element 2(as an example).

The output of this instruction gives me 5. I am trying to continue the iteration of obtaining more column 2 elements like : 7 because 5 is connected to 7 and continue the iteration  to obtaining 8 because 7 is connected to 8. I am trying to make each of my new column 2 element into a column 1 element and extract the corresponding column 2 element till its a deadend. In this case continue till 0 and it automatically stops. Currently I am doing this manually currently but the challenge comes for bigger data. I get many text files and sorting them is difficult for the next iteration.

I believe arrays can be used to store intermediate results but i am not well versed with using arrays. Can anyone kindly help me out here?

Comment: Manually I am getting 5; 7; 8; 9; 0 on separate text files.

Comment: Your question title isn't very clear.  Maybe change it to "transitively join on output from join" or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `join` is a good choice of tool if you want to perform something radically different than it was designed for.  The following simple Awk script will follow the transitive relations you are describing, and doesn't require sorted input.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }
    { n=$1; while (n in a) { print a[n]; n=a[n]; } }' Sample.txt first.txt
```

However, this requires that all of `Sample.txt` can be fit in memory.

If you need multiple "from to" pairs with the same "from" value, the data structure needs to be a little more complicated.  Perhaps like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1] = (a[$1] ? a[$1] "\n" $2 : $2); next }
    function emit (key) {
      if (key ~ /\n/) {
        split(key, k, /\n/);
        for (n in k) {
          emit(k[n])
        }
      } else if (key in a) { print a[key]; emit (a[key]) }
    }
    { emit($1) }' Sample.txt first.txt
```

Comment: tripleee  thanks for your response. I tried your instruction and I am getting 5 7 9 0. However if you see the sample.txt there are two column 2 elements corresponding to 7. Can both be written without the first one being omitted. Thanks for your suggestion. I will get more familiarised with awk. Also, I am unable to comprehend your last statement regarding fit in memory.

Comment: If you have a large input file, theoretically the array which is read into memory could be bigger than Awk can handle.  I don't think that's going to be a concern in real life, but if we are talking of millions of lines, maybe you should elaborate on operational limitations.

Comment: The relation `7 9` will completely replace `7 8` in the Awk script; a later destination will overwrite an earlier one, the way it's written now.  It's not clear what the script should do in this situation.  It could handle both relations, at the expense of some additional complexity.

Comment: My file will be less than 1500 lines so as you it won't be a concern for awk to handle. I was actually trying to find the influence of 2 over the entire data set and hence require all the corresponding column 2 elements as discussed above. How could I tweak your instruction in order to retain 8(in this case it stops for 8 because no column 2 elements) and proceed to 9 which has column 2 elements?